# Not able to run jsp page in my Spring Boot Application in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, jsp, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I've been trying to run a basic Spring Application which is written in intelliJ IDE. This is a basic Hello World application, and I've been following a tutorial. What I couldn't solve here is, I've just added following dependency to be able to run .jsp pages as well in Spring App.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Below part is the logs:

```
2017-02-06 22:06:57.294 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/login]
2017-02-06 22:06:57.294 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /login
2017-02-06 22:06:57.295 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.orcunyilmaz.springboot.web.controller.LoginController.loginMessage()]
2017-02-06 22:06:57.295 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/login] is: -1
2017-02-06 22:06:57.296 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2017-02-06 22:06:57.296 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name '/login'
2017-02-06 22:06:57.296 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name '/login'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp//login.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2017-02-06 22:06:57.296 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name '/login'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp//login.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-02-06 22:06:57.297 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp//login.jsp] in InternalResourceView '/login'
2017-02-06 22:06:57.298 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]
2017-02-06 22:06:57.298 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp
2017-02-06 22:06:57.299 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]
2017-02-06 22:06:57.299 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] are [/**]
2017-02-06 22:06:57.299 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] are {}
2017-02-06 22:06:57.299 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@2e59cce9]]] and 1 interceptor
2017-02-06 22:06:57.299 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] is: -1
2017-02-06 22:06:57.300 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-02-06 22:06:57.300 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2017-02-06 22:06:57.300 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2017-02-06 22:06:57.301 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2017-02-06 22:06:57.301 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2017-02-06 22:06:57.302 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
2017-02-06 22:06:57.303 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2017-02-06 22:06:57.314 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
2017-02-06 22:06:57.314 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@75420106] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2017-02-06 22:06:57.314 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@75420106] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-02-06 22:06:57.314 DEBUG 6320 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

localhost:8080/login always shows me this page:
[image]

I've made a search a bit, and realized that I am not able to apply my lastly added jars (which cames from the dependency) to the project. But I also couldn't find how to add it.

I believe I needed to add new artifact to my project. The answers that I've found in the internet is not providing the exact place that I need to click or change. So any help will be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: provided jars aren't part of the class path when launching an application from IntellIJ. Next to that your view name is resolved as `/login` whereas I would expect it to be `login` as.a proper name which would resolve to `/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp`. Also have you taken care reading the JSP limitation section in the Spring Boot reference guide?

Comment: I see that provided jars aren't part of the class path, but I do not know how to add them. And thanks, I've changed /login to login. According to tutorial, adding that dependency will give me the ability to use jsp pages in spring boot app.

Comment: It will but NOT in Intellij as it will not include provided dependencies on the class path because well they are provided...

Comment: Okay so I understand that the problem's root cause is a different. Sorry for misunderstanding. What do you think about the problem I got then? @M.Deinum

Comment: Well actually the problem is Intellij (well actually it behaves like it should with provided scoped dependencies imho). If you run the same through maven with `mvn spring-boot:run` it will work (so you could create a run configuration which does this to work around the IntelliJ issue). See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107048

Answer (score 0):

The problem is IntelliJ. Just restart the ide.